# JQuery UI Dialog submit form with multiple form inputs

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog, form-submit

I have a form with three inputs: Save, Delete, and Exit. When Delete is clicked, I pop a JQuery UI Dialog box to confirm that the user wants to delete that data. They have two buttons as options: Delete or Cancel. Cancel works fine and closes the Dialog box. If they click Delete, I wish to submit the original form and delete the data as if the Dialog box was not there, which is not working. I click it and nothing appears to happen.

I am attempting to submit the "update_purchase" form but simulate using the "delete_purchase" input to convey information. With the below code, once I click "Delete" on the Dialog box nothing happens; however, if I click "Cancel" to exit the dialog box and then click "Exit" on the original form, I find the entry has been deleted.

Thanks for any and all help.

```
<form method="post" id="update_purchase" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="{{ url }}">
...
<input type="Submit" name="save" value="Save">
<input type="Submit" name="delete_purchase" id="delete" value="Delete">
<input type="Submit" name="exit_edit" value="Exit">

// Confirm Delete dialog
    $(function() {
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            resizable: false,
            height: 180,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                "Delete": function() {
                    $("#update_purchase").submit( function(eventObj){
                        $('<input />').attr('type', 'hidden')
                            .attr('name', "delete_purchase")
                            .attr('value', "Delete")
                            .appendTo('#update_purchase');
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    return true;                            
                    });
                },
                "Cancel": function() {
                $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                        }
                    }                           
        });
        $("#delete").click(function() {
            $("#dialog").dialog("open");
            return false;
        });
    });
```

Comment: `$('<input />')` should be replaced by `$('input')`.

Comment: Thanks for the response. After replacing that , the behavior is the same, except once I exit Dialog using "Cancel" and then click "Exit" on the main form, I notice the data is not deleted, whereas previously it would be.